# How to change the delegate to be an instance of an object

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml-parsing, delegates, tree-structure

I'm new to ObjectiveC and am trying to parse an XML file as described in this article:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/XMLParsing/Articles/ConstructingTrees.html

Trouble is, I don't understand what the article means in step 3 by "The method that creates and initializes the object also sets it to be the new delegate of the NSXMLParser instance."

Does this require adding a method to the MyElement class, or is the code added into the top level object?

Can anyone give a code sample of what they mean here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the delegate that will handle the parser functions.

On your .h file:

```
@interface MyParser : NSObject <NSXMLParserDelegate>
```

On your .m file:

```
NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:dataToParse];
[parser setDelegate:self];
```

That will link your file to the parser and will expect your class to have all the methods to handle the parsing work:

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict;
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
```

Fill the behavior of the methods to actually do the parsing.

Comment: Thanks! Which .m file do I put that code in?

I have the default AppDelegate files, and the ViewController files that go along with the storyboard as well.

Then I created the new class MyElement, so does the above go in the MyElement files? I already have the first delegate setup in the ViewController files. so then I would have two sets of Delegate code?

Comment: On the file doing the parsing. Check the this tutorial: http://wiki.cs.unh.edu/wiki/index.php/Parsing_XML_data_with_NSXMLParser

Comment: Thanks again! the example you pointed me to helped me figure it out!

Answer (score 0):

What it means is when you create the MyElement instance, you set it as the delegate of the NSXMLParser.